# Get property name of changed item - Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

Are there any listener in IMap which allow  to get the name of the **property** which has been changed?

For example:
I have a map `[{Key}, {"foo":"exampleFoo", "bar":"exampleBar"}]`, if something change in `foo` value, is there a way to get the name of the property?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: This article can be useful for you [Tracking which entity properties have changed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128113/tracking-which-entity-properties-have-changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the entry value by using `entryEvent.getValue()` in the `EntryEvent` parameter. Please remember to set `includeValue` parameter to `true` when you are adding the listener.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have already done something like `addEntryListener(listener, true)`, but when I recive an event, I want to get the name of the field and its value. In the previous example, if something change in exampleFoo I want to retrieve the new incoming value and `foo` (or the respective proerty name). Is it possibile?